# C++ Compilation issue: object file not found

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to compile a project that I dowloaded from a repository using svn and imported it to eclipse in a gentoo linux OS. I installed all libs and dependecies but it doesn't compile issuing that it cannot find .o files.

The error is

```
g++: error: source/fakeFolder/fakeFile.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [source/fakeFolder/fakeFile.o] Error 1
```

Never encountered this issue.. any ideas?

Comment: Well, since this is such an odd error I was thinking that this was something that has nothing to do with the code itself, maybe something missing in the makefile generated by eclipse? I mean, each .cpp file originate a .o file, am I right? And the compiler says it doesn't find a .o file that correspond to the .cpp files I have in the project.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not able to locate `fakeFile.o` which is an object file required for linking the program. The repository `Makefile` *possibly* forgot to compile `fakeFile.cpp`.

Comment: I'm guessing you are right, but it is weird since eclipse generates makefiles automatically and I've never had a problem like this. It is a simple project with a main function and a couple of extra .cpp and .h files with classes declared. I'll check the makefile to see if I can figure this out.